# Modify a source based on strings in the current URL

Tags: javascript, php

I am a little bit stuck trying to get a tracking code to work for my website.

Every click to my website through a tracker inserts a randomly generated unique string within the URL. For example, http://www.examplepage.com/?sub_ref=333ktcm1ckpv2uvd

When someone does goes through a step by step process on my website, a PHP script will load containing various variables, one of which is an external javascript:

```
$script = <script type="text/javascript" id="js1" src="https://www.example.com/load.php?id=8bb1ff8aa970aa5f018dcce821dc6251"></script>
```

In order for me to facilitate the tracking, I want to be able to add the unique string in the URL into the javascript. The idea is that I can track when someone clicks my website and then completes an entry with an external script. For example:

```
 $script = <script type="text/javascript" id="js1" src="https://www.example.com/load.php?id=8bb1ff8aa970aa5f018dcce821dc6251?sub_ref=333ktcm1ckpv2uvd"></script>
```

Could someone advise the best way to achieve this? I've been playing around with this for most of the day without success.

I should add, at the point I want the unique ID added onto the script, the URL on my website is http://www.examplepage.com/?sub_ref=333ktcm1ckpv2uvd#submit-entry

Comment: Show the attempts that you've come up with and describe the results and explain how they differ from what you want.

Comment: I've tried:

`src="https://www.example.com/load.php?id=8bb1ff8aa970aa5f018dcce821dc6251&sub_ref=<?php echo urlencode($_GET['sub_ref'])?>"`

But this didn’t do anything. I am completely new to this, so I am a bit out of my depth.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are close, just need to point to the right query....

```
src="https://www.example.com/load.php?id=8bb1ff8aa970aa5f018dcce821dc6251&sub_ref=<?php echo urlencode($_GET['sub_ref'])?>"
```

Looks fine (though from the example you gave you shouldn't need the urlencode).

It is really hard to tell what is going on though without some actual code.... (which is likely why nobody is answering you..... - nor can I give you much of an answer......)

However, as a 'troubleshooting' tip......

You have to know what you have as variables to work with at any given moment, so learn to stop the code at any given point and take a look what the code sees.

In this case, a good one would be to see what is in the $_SERVER array to see what links are really available before trying to build the reference link (this will tell you where you really are as well as how the user got to you, etc. - a wealth of info to be sure!)

```
echo __LINE__ . " here, we look at _SERVER "; print_r($_SERVER); echo "<br>";
```

Another good one at this point is the $_GET, which will tell you what is in the query string as an array....

```
echo __LINE__ . " here, we look at _GET "; print_r($_GET); echo "<br>";
```

Having the results of both those will tell you that you actually have the data you think you do (and that is quite often the reason things don't work like you expect!)

(you can also add a

```
die();
```

after any line to make the code stop.....  Lots of ways to do this, and the most important part is just seeing what is going on!

Use the above, change your question to include more code and show what you are getting in $_SERVER and $_GET at that point and you will get some great, exact answers, I'm sure!

**EDIT** (after a bit more info.... - but still no full code..... :( again, seeing the script around all this would help get this done..... not sure why you aren't including it...)

Obviously you are in PHP at this moment (as it is a PHP error - the script would tell us that...) and your code won't work in PHP.

You have....

```
$script = <script type="text/javascript" id="js1" src="https://www.example.com/load.php?id=8bb1ff8aa?&sub_ref=<?php echo ($_GET['sub_ref']); ?>"></script>
```

and

> PHP message: PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in
>   /home/admin/web/exampledomain.com/public_html/settings.php on line 13"
>   while reading response header from upstream

Which is telling you the issue - - - you can't write JS inside PHP!  You can make it a variable, then use it later, or you could 'jump in/out' of PHP/HTML to do it, but you must remember what language you are in and respect that language's rules.

So, you *could* have:

```
$script = '<script type="text/javascript" id="js1" src="https://www.example.com/load.php?id=8bb1ff8aa?&sub_ref=' . $_GET['sub_ref'] . '"></script>';
```

Or, 'jump in/out' with:

```
// PHP code ......
// 'jump out'....
?>
<!-- now you are in HTML and can do some JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" id="js1" src="https://www.example.com/load.php?id=8bb1ff8aa?&sub_ref=<?php echo ($_GET['sub_ref']); ?>"></script>
<!-- where you had correctly 'jumped', but improperly mixed... -->
<!-- now, back to PHP... ->
<? // and you can do more PHP code here.....
```

You have to respect the language - and where you are at any point in the code!

If you still have issues, INCLUDE THE FULL CODE AROUND THIS (I'm sure it isn't rocket science gov't secret stuff, so save us all some time so you can get the help you are asking for, please!

EDIT:

in your settings.php the link shows as

```
src="https://www.example.com/load.php?id=8bb1ff8aa?&sub_ref=' . $_GET['sub_ref']
```

However, you say in the button it is

```
src="https://www.example.com.net/test.php?id=8bb1ff8&amp;sub_ref="
```

Your code is not clear on how things are going...... (does this sound familiar?  SHOW THE CODE AS IT IS PROCESSED.....  - I can't {and now, won't be able to - I've put too much time on this and am getting 'looks'...} try to guess where that weird change came from.  You need to show something that is logical.....

and, prove that you have the _GET - use the print_r just before the _GET to make sure you have the data as it is being processed (sometimes with PHP you have to do some 'tricks' to keep the data on one page and use it on another.....  there are several ways to do it, but until I understand your flow and what you are trying to do overall {and mostly, why you are using so many pages.... - it could be an overall design/flow issue...}, it is really hard to get a picture of what you are trying to accomplish..)

SO is not really a training facility - and I have other projects (I'm allowed a bit of time each day to answer questions, etc. - part of the 'give back to the community' policy around here, but my primary work is on paid projects {I'm sure you understand...}, so I can't do more today, but if you give some clear 'steps' on what is going on and errors you see, etc. I can look at this again tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Apologies, the reason I've not included all the files is that there is a lot of of them. I've edited my last post to include, hopefully, what I believe to be the relevant bits.

Comment: @AndyH, it is better, but inconsistent.... - see my edit.....  (and, note for the future - you should edit your QUESTION, not make an answer yourself.  Reason for this is that, as I'm editing my answer I can see your question, but not the other answer!)

Comment: I appreciate your answer on this. I have tried to include the `echo __LINE__ . " here, we look at _GET "; print_r($_GET); echo "<br>";` in the final-step.php the result is completely blank so the URL string is not being picked up by the script. I will look into your comment about keeping the data from one page to the next, thanks.

Comment: the _GET  will only be there when the PHP page is loaded (like http://example.com?itshere=true) - but you are including it (I'm guessing your user first saw the '_GET' page, then you redirected them???), so it won't be there.  You have to pay attention to the FLOW of things (which is why we keep asking for the code as it will run...) to know where you are, what variables are available at any moment and such (much like the 'jumping' from PHP/HTML/JS - it all has a 'flow'.....).  Look up things like using SESSION variables and 'hidden' html input values - depending on the flow, these are great.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @CFP Support that's really useful.

So based on your advice, I've managed to work out that using the below displays the correct URL string that I'm looking to add within the javascript.

> https://example.com/test/test.php?sub_ref=230948324095

`<?php
echo __LINE__ . " here, we look at _GET "; print_r($_GET); echo "<br>";?>`

> 8 here, we look at _GET Array ( [sub_ref] => 230948324095 )

So based on the above, I believe I should be using:

```
<?php echo ($_GET['sub_ref'])?>"
```

The problem I've got now, is that if I use the following, I end up with an error:

`$script = <script type="text/javascript" id="js1" src="https://www.example.com/load.php?id=8bb1ff8aa?&sub_ref=<?php echo ($_GET['sub_ref']); ?>"></script>`

> PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in
>   /home/admin/web/exampledomain.com/public_html/settings.php
>   on line 13" while reading response header from upstream

EDIT:

This is where I am at currently. I've made the change you recommended (first one) which doesn't product an error, however the sub_ref in the button that loads the script is still blank.

settings.php file

```
<?php
         // Set the referral network
             $network = 'A';
         // Set your submit code below.
             $onClick_code = 'call_referral()';
         // Set your the referral script below.
             $script = '
<script type="text/javascript" id="js1" src="https://www.example.com/load.php?id=8bb1ff8aa?&sub_ref=' . $_GET['sub_ref'] . '"></script>';

         ?>
```

final-step.php

```
<?php
    require_once '../settings.php';
    ?>
<h1>Submitting Data</h1>
<p class="second-paragraph">Please wait while we process your data.</p>
<div class="data-processing-wrapper">
    <div class="data-processing-inner-wrapper">
        <div class="cssload-loader-walk">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <span class="console-msg"></span>
        <div class="data-verification-wrapper">
            <h3>Data Verification</h3>
            <p>Thank you, you are almost done submitting your data.
                <br>Click on the Submit Now button below to submit your data.
                </p>
                <div class="button-wrapper data-verification-button-wrapper">
                    <a class="button data-verification-button" 
                        <?php if ($network == 'A' || $network == 'B') {?> onclick="
                        <?php if (!empty($onClick_code)) { echo $onClick_code; } ?>"
                        <?php } ?>>Submit Now
                    </a>
                    <?php if ($network == 'A' && !empty($script)) { echo $script; } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="progressBarConsole" class="console-loadbar">
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

From inspecting the Submit Now button in Chrome, this is what it shows (the ?sub_ref is blank):

```
<div class="button-wrapper data-verification-button-wrapper">
                <a class="button data-verification-button" onclick="call_referral()">Submit Now</a>
                <script type="text/javascript" id="js1" src="https://www.example.com.net/test.php?id=8bb1ff8&amp;sub_ref="></script>            </div>
```

Am I correct in assuming that the sub_ref does not appear because the script is not being when the page is opened (only when final-step.php runs)?